# HTML5 videos from KnowledgeVision and Youtube not working on Android 4.x with Phonegap 3.6.3

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video, phonegap-build

When I add video embed codes from either KnowledgeVision or Youtube to my Phonegap application, the video fails to load.

This works on iOS so is strictly an Android problem.

Hardware acceleration is true and the videos do work when accessed from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The access origin tag in my config.xml was

```
<access origin="https://*.mydomain.com" />
```

It turns out that iOS is ignoring the access origin tag which is why it works on iOS but not Android. The Phonegap documentation says:

```
NOTE: Some network requests do not go through the Cordova Whitelist. This includes <video> and <audio> resouces...
```

But because the embed codes are actually iFrames and not video tags they are blocked even though the videos they contain wouldn't be blocked.

This fixes the issue:

```
<access origin="*">
```